# repeat () repeats a subscription without updating

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
const source = of(Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5));
const example = source.pipe(delay(3000),repeat() );
example.subscribe((x) => {
  console.log(x);
})
```

repeat () repeats a subscription without updating source

Comment: What do you mean by 'repeats subscription' and 'updating source'?

Comment: I think they want to re-calculate the random string, which is impossible, because it is already calculated before anything RxJS is involved. It's essentially passed as a constant, RxJS cannot know how to calculate another value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const source = timer(3000);
    const example = source.pipe( repeat() );
    const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5)));
```

i solved my problem

Comment: You don't need repeat, you can configure timer to repeat itself.